# Block IP access to specific page only

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to block access from a certain IP address to one page of a website only, not the entire website.

Here's what I have, but doesn't seem to be working (I switch out offending IP to mine and am still abel to access after refresh/cache dump etc)

```
<Files specificpage.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from XX.XXX.XXX.XX
</Files>
```

Is there a better way of doing this or does anything jump out here?
thx

Answer (score 1):

You can actually `mod_rewrite` rules for finer control here. Place this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =XX.XXX.XXX.XX
RewriteRule ^specificpage\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Yes this is no doubt better than using `<Files>` as it gives lot more features than `Files` directive.